# Symfony handle Api request by form

Tags: php, symfony, http-post, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4.4 as a restful API with no views at all. I want to avoid annoying code like this:

```php
        $email = $request->get('email');
        $password = $request->get('password');
        $newUser = new User();
        $newUser->setEmail($email)->setPassword($password));
```

Because if one entity has a lot of properties I have to spend a lot of time getting every variable from the *request->get('property')*. So I decided to try to use Symfony forms.

But I always get this error:

```
Expected argument of type \"array\", \"null\" given at property path \"roles\"."
```

---

My user class

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"public"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @Groups({"public"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     * @Groups({"public"})
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\NotNull
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"public"})
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"public"})
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Log", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $logs;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
        $this->logs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = strtolower($email);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime(); // updates the updatedAt field

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of createdAt
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of createdAt
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Log[]
     */
    public function getLogs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->logs;
    }

    public function addLog(Log $log): self
    {
        if (!$this->logs->contains($log)) {
            $this->logs[] = $log;
            $log->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLog(Log $log): self
    {
        if ($this->logs->contains($log)) {
            $this->logs->removeElement($log);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($log->getUser() === $this) {
                $log->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The form that I've created simply using the *makerbundle*

```php
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options):void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('roles')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('createdAt')
            ->add('updatedAt')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver):void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
```

And my controller

```php
    public function postUsersAction(Request $request): View
    {

        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $form->submit($data);

        return $this->view(['message' => $form->isValid()], Response::HTTP_OK); // for testing purposes
```

The data that I'm sending through postman is something like:

```
email=duuuu@gmail.com&password=1234
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Controller:

```php
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $form->submit($request->request->all(), false);

        return $this->view(['message' => $form->isValid()], Response::HTTP_OK); // for testing purposes
```

And I also had to disable csrf protection by:

```php
 public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver):void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setRoles function does expect an array as a parameter. But as you are leaving the roles field or value blank by not passing any value to your url, "null" is submitted. Therefore, you get an error that an array was expected but null was passed to the roles field.

To set an empty array as the default value when no value is supplied you might want to have a look at the "empty_data" option for form fields (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#empty-data)

So in your form type you could be doing:

```
$builder->add('roles', null, ['empty_data' => []])
```

which would set the roles to be an empty array whenever you submit the form without a value for the roles.

If you only want to update a few values (as in a PATCH Request), the submit function accepts a second parameter that defines whether missing fields will be overwritten with null values or removed from the form (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html)

Calling

```
$form->submit($data, false);
```

would, therefore, keep your object roles as they are and only update fields you passed with your request.

Comment: I added the empty data as you said, and even the required false property. 
``` php
 ->add('roles', [
                'required' => false,
                'empty_data' => []
            ]) ```

and 

``` php
        $form->submit($data, false);
```

But I still get:
``` php
Expected argument of type \"string or null\", \"array\" given
```

Comment: I also tried to see what happens when I pass the roles, but the exact problem occurs![img link](https://i.imgur.com/KYluekp.png)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something. The options are the third argument for the "add" function, to define options you need to set the field type as the second argument. The field type needs to be "string or null" so it complains because your option array is the second parameter. As you don't want to render your form you can just pass "null". So it needs to look like this:

`->add('roles', null, ['empty_data' => []]` I fixed it in my original answer